# Google Visualization Options Not Working

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I can't get the first series of the data to be graphed as a line instead of a bar. Also, several options I try do not work, including having a title (crazy ambitious, right?).

Why doesn't this work? Where is the title? I also can't figure out how to animate on startup even though it should literally work (attempt not shown below).

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table','line','corechart','bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw);

function draw(){
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Referrals', '%','A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
   ['Adams',  {v: .3684, f: '36.84%'}, 0,0,3,9,4,14,1],
   ['Chalk',  {v: .9118, f: '91.18%'}, 0,0,2,16,12,21,1],
   ['Forby',  {v: 2.0909, f: '209.09%'}, 0,0,3,17,9,12,1],
   ['Koehler', {v: .056, f: '5.26%'},  0,0,0,13,6,13,0],
   ['Burrey',  {v: 0, f: '-'},    0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   ['Roach',  {v: .1765, f: '19.65%'}, 0,0,7,43,18,32,1]
    ]);

    var tempOptions = {
        title: 'tesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssst',
        series: {
          0: {axis: 'Percent',type: 'line'},
          1: {axis: 'Count'},
          2: {axis: 'Count'},
          3: {axis: 'Count'},
          4: {axis: 'Count'},
          5: {axis: 'Count'},
          6: {axis: 'Count'},
          7: {axis: 'Count'}
        },
        axes: {
          y: {
            Percent: {label: '% for Hazard Grade'},
            Count: {label: 'Hazard Grade Count'}
          }
        }
    };
  
    
     var tempTable = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  
   tempTable.draw(data,tempOptions);
     }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several config options that don't work with *material* charts

[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

*material* --> `google.charts.Bar` -- using --> `packages: ['bar']`

recommend using *core* chart instead...

*core* --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- using --> `packages: ['corechart']`
or `google.visualization.BarChart`, `google.visualization.ComboChart`, etc...

there is an option to get *core* chart close to look & feel of *material*

`theme: 'material'`

Comment: You also answered my other question haha. You're on the ball. But in all seriousness I'm totally ditching material charts. So many headaches. Thanks for the help!